# Less setup: Bootstrap row grid not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am new to LESS, started working with it and the issue I am facing is that I can't get the bootstrap row/column to work. I want three thumbnails to appear side by side (i.e. three columns in one row) but it won't happen. Is it because I have messed up any of the LESS files?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Home</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:900,700,400,500|Open+Sans:400,700,300|Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <!-- the bootstrap compiled file outputted from LESS -->
  <link href="_/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <!-- compiled version of my styles, outputted from LESS file where I edit my styles -->
  <link href="_/css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 </head>
 <body>
 <section class="container">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/blacksea.jpg" alt="...">
       </a>
     </div> <!-- thumbnail 1 -->
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/blacksea.jpg" alt="...">
       </a>
     </div> <!-- thumbnail 2 -->
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="images/blacksea.jpg" alt="...">
       </a>
     </div> <!-- thumbnail 3 -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
   </section> <!-- container -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

I tested my code on a normal boostrap setup (without Less) and it is working perfectly fine. But when the same code in my LESS set up the pictures get stacked vertically rather than horizontally.

Having seen it work on jsfiddle, I think the reason it is not working locally is because there may be some issue with my Bootstrap import, because for a verification, when I tried [to do this feature of Bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21PUh.png) it did not work and I got [this instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGbyy.png), so something to do with Bootstrap?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you include the head section so we can see how you include the stylesheets?

Comment: Did you give images height and width?

Comment: @Gert-JanKooijmans I have now included the header section as well, thank you

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I didn't give image height and width, but then the same is working when use the simple bootstrap version (without less), and having not given image height and width has also been working okay in the past. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: what does this mean? `but then the same is working when use the simple bootstrap version (without less)` do you mean it works as expected when you don't add your css?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sorry I meant it works without giving image dimensions (the height and width) in the simple Bootstrap version, the attached screenshot that shows the expected output is with exactly the same settings but without using LESS.

Comment: Can you provide css?

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I have pasted the content of mystyles.less above, thank you

Comment: This is so weird, cus to me works fine!! Without inspect, we cannot do anything, It is almost impossible to find the bug you are facing. Why you don't provide a fiddle? I think in this way we could help you. @Ros

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi If doing it right, I have created this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dwnv7zw4/#&togetherjs=igotSAvhNv

Comment: @Ros, I edited your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dwnv7zw4/3/, hope it helps!

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi, thank you, I think it was
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
this bit, which makes it work fine on jsfiddle, but on my local copy with LESS it still does not work lol

Comment: Yes, that was causing that problem. Cus classes col-md-* are give to a specific screen width.(lg-large, md-medium, and xs-extra small). :)

Comment: Inspect images and columns width, see if columns take any width! @Ros

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I have tried inspecting the images and columns in Chrome but I really don't understand why it still isn't working locally, any other suggestions?

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I couldn't attach screenshots in comments so I had to edit the main post above for showing you that it may be an issue with my bootstrap version, please take a look at the last part of the above post.

Comment: @Ros, it is hard for me to find the issue, I could verify anything if you provide a fiddle with the issue. I could inspect it, and I think I could find a solution. But, showing just images is hopeless :(

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi no worries mate lol thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @ros, I wish I could help you! Hope you'll find a solution! Best of luck! 